# How do you truncate a sentence at the nearest space?

Tags: ruby

We have a sentence and a character limit.  We want to truncate the sentence if it exceeds the character limit, but only at a space, not in the middle of a word.

This is what we have so far:

```
  def shortened_headline(max_length)
    return @headline unless @headline.length > max_length
    @headline[0..max_length]
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having trimmed the headline you can use `rindex` to find the index of something from the right of an array or string.

Something like:

```
sub_length=@headline[0..max_length].rindex(' ')
```

Will give you the location of the last space in the headline. You can also use it with a regex if you wanted to find the last non-alphanumeric character in the string so you could break on the last space or punctuation.

[More on rindex here.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rindex)

Answer (score 3):

Rails extends the `String` class with a variety of convenience methods, among them a `truncate` method which you can pass a `:separator` option. Even if you don't use Rails, you could simply copy their implementation. See the documentation at

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-truncate

(you can click "show source" to see the actual implemetation)

Comment: This is why Rails is so awesome. It's like they actually have thought of _everything_.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [String#index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-index). It finds index of the first occurrence of the string, and it also accepts and offset.

**NOTE:** This implementation cuts the string in the first space **after** the max_length (which, I just realized, might not be what you want). If you need to cut on the first space before max_length, see @glenatron's answer.

```
def shortened_headline(headline, max_length)
  return headline if headline.length < max_length

  space_pos = headline.index(' ', max_length)
  headline[0..space_pos-1]
end

h = 'How do you truncate a sentence at the nearest space?'

h[0..4] # => "How d"
shortened_headline(h, 5) # => "How do"

h[0..10] # => "How do you "
shortened_headline(h, 10) # => "How do you"

h[0..15] # => "How do you trunc"
shortened_headline(h, 15) # => "How do you truncate"
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ActiveSupport's core-extensions for Strings, specifically the [`truncate`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#truncate) method.

From the docs:

```
The method truncate returns a copy of its receiver truncated after a given length:

    "Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!".truncate(20)
    # => "Oh dear! Oh dear!..."
```

Access it like this:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_support/core_ext/string/filters'
irb(main):002:0> 'how now brown cow'.truncate(10)
=> "how now..."
```

The `truncate` method has the ability to turn off the elipsis if you don't want that extra adornment.

ActiveSupport was refactored a while back to allow us to cherry-pick the features we want without needing to pull in the complete library. It's chock-full of goodness. The [core-extension page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) has a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
@headline[/.{,#{max_length}}(?: |\z)/]
```